# else part not executing in php if condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I've got this project on DBMS.  My form is working if I enter the correct username and password.. but it shows only a blank page when i enter wrong details.. It's not executing the else part.. It if part is working fine.. Can anyone help me.. I'm new to PHP.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>  

 <?php
 include 'connection.php';
 SESSION_START();
 $user = $_POST['registeredEmail'];
 $pass = $_POST['registeredpassword'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$user."' and password = '".$pass."';";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($qry) or die(mysql_error());
if($result) 
{
$_SESSION['UserName'] = $result['name'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("Sign In Successful");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "sell.php";';
echo '</script>';



}
else
{
//  header('Location: index.php');
echo 'sign in unsuccessful';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("Sign In UnSuccessful. Either Email or password or both are wrong.. please try again or Sign Up");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
echo '</script>'; 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you looked into your source code? Is your page really blank ?

Comment: Please, please, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems in your code. Let's 1st focus on how to fix this. Replace your code with below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".$user."' and `password` = '".$pass."';";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($qry) == 1) 
{
```

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Don't store the password in plain-text. Use an encryption algorithm such as md5.

[Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

Comment: That, and it seems to store plaintext passwords. I hope this code never sees any real life application.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that code has issues at the beginning

Comment: I'm just using the code to rum via xampp on localhost.. will comply by your suggestions.. Thanks a ton to all you guys  for helping ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if($result)`

you can use `if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0)`

Comment: You would want it to be `if(mysql_num_rows($qry) ==1)` since its a login form, and you dont want more than 1 match

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 include 'connection.php';
 SESSION_START();
 $user = $_POST['registeredEmail'];
 $pass = $_POST['registeredpassword'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".$user."' and `password` = '".$pass."';";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($num==1) 
{
$result = mysql_fetch_array($qry) or die(mysql_error());

$_SESSION['UserName'] = $result['name'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("Sign In Successful");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "sell.php";';
echo '</script>';



}
else
{
//  header('Location: index.php');
echo 'sign in unsuccessful';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("Sign In UnSuccessful. Either Email or password or both are wrong.. please try again or Sign Up");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
echo '</script>'; 
}
?>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Basicly your if statement always conditions to true, so the else statement is never reached. If you check a different condition like vivek suggests, where you check if your query has exactly 1 match (since I suppose you will want a user to have only 1 account) the statement can also be false and thus it will skip to the else statement.